# How to change built-in templates

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

Is there a way to change the built-in templates?

Concrete example: I want to change the template that is used when creating an event invocator. I want to change the visibility of the generated method as well as the the name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to template explorer ( `ReSharper > Tools > Template explorer` )
2. Search the desired template and click on `Edit Template` or double click to open it.
3. Edit the template as you want and save it.

More info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html)

Comment: Please note that I am talking about the built in templates. Those don't appear there

Comment: I have all of them... Maybe is problem of the selected layer?

Comment: Can you please show me a screenshot of the template that is used when Resharper creates an event invocator?

Comment: I haven't it, also I'm using resharper-7.0. I hope someone else can help you

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, have you found how to do it?

Comment: No, I haven't found out how to do it